# How to define vector using set-builder notation

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors

I need a vector of length $J$ where each element can take values 0/1 and where the sum of the elements is no greater than $N$. Can I write it as follows?

$$ S=\left(s_{j}=\{0,1\} \ \forall j \leq J : \sum_{j=1}^J s_j \leq N \right)$$.

You can think of $S$ as a vector of binary random variables constrained to sum to no more than $N$.

Comment: You can't write this as $S=...$, because you aren't specifying exactly what the vector is - you're just stating a property it has.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ be the set of such vectors.

$T:=\{(x_1,\ldots ,x_J)\in\{0,1\}^J|x_1+\ldots +x_J\leq N\}$

Comment: Or [more concisely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Definition), $\{x\in\{0,\,1\}^J|\Vert x\Vert_1\le N\}$.